# How do I stop my animation in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am making a game in javascript. I have a scrolling background. I am trying to stop the animation when the game is paused using `(#thingo).stop`. However it isn't working.

The code I am using to animate is:

```
  (function bgScroll() {
      $('#background').css('left', 0);
      $('#background').css('top', 0);
      $('#background').animate({backgroundPosition: '-=10'}, 20, bgScroll);
  })();
```

I am then using this to try to stop it, however it isn't working.

```
  $('#background').stop();
```

Thanks

Comment: You are calling the same function at complete callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag to determine whether or not to call `.css()`, `.animate()` and same function again

```
  $('#background').data("stop", false);

  (function bgScroll() {
    if (!$("#background").data("stop")) {
      $('#background').css('left', 0);
      $('#background').css('top', 0);
      $('#background').animate({backgroundPosition: '-=10'}, 20, bgScroll)
    };
  })();
```

```
  $('#background').data("stop", true).stop();
```